# Cutting text between two commas, excluding follow up text

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I'm having a heard time figuring out how to extract the IP information out of an output similar to this:

```
Fri Jun  9 19:01:54 2017,10.0.0.65,devi1,0,unknown os
Fri Jun  9 19:01:54 2017,10.0.0.55,host1,0,unknown os
Fri Jun  9 19:01:54 2017,10.0.0.35,srv01,0,unknown os
Sat Jun 10 23:11:13 2017,10.0.0.10,switch.domain.com,0,unknown os
```

Any tips on how I can, from that output, get:

```
10.0.0.65
10.0.0.55
10.0.0.35
10.0.0.10
```

Running on Bash 4.3.30 in Linux.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $2}' file`

Comment: A note for those who follow: if  your data is CSV (comma separated values) as opposed to simply being comma delimited, you'll want to use a csv library, or something like `csvtool` -- there's a lot more to CSV than commas and text, as it might at first appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could do this with `awk` or `sed`, for a simple extraction between fixed delimiters [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) is probably the best fit:

```
$ cut -d, -f2 < input
```

Comment: No need to use an indirection ('`<`'); `cut` takes a file as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' /path/to/input
```

With `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f2 /path/to/input
```

Comment: one approach - from my comment, the other - from @ilkkachu answer